# how to query results from a command in a bash script

Tags: bash

I have the following bash script:

```
 #!/bin/bash 
  echo "GET load test"     
  for i in $(seq 1 50) do
     MY_RESULTS = "$(curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET http://localhost/test/store/widget/123)"
     echo "$MY_RESULTS" 
  done
```

I'm not sure why but the results don't print out.  When I change the code to the following, it works:

```
 curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET http://localhost/test/store/widget/123)"
```

Then the results just display on the screen.  Ultimately, I'd like to search the contents of the results for a particular string value like "200 OK"

I created another test script to test how to save, and echo values out to the screen and it works.  It look like this:

```
MY_VAR="$(find -name loadtest.sh)"
echo "$MY_VAR"
```

The results it displays is:

> ./loadtest.sh

I can't see what's different about this variable called MY_VAR and the one in my load test

Comment: spaces in assignment should give you a problem, try: `MY_RESULTS="$(curl...`

Comment: And a new line or a semicolon before `do` would be a good idea.

Comment: dan08 - bingo!  that worked

Comment: @dan08 do you want to post as answer so I can accept?  Also, can you tell me how to grep the results as well for the string "200 OK" ?

Comment: @Happydevdays New question → new question.

Comment: as 1st help, always try run your script with `-x` like: `bash -x script.sh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash, you can not have whitespace about the equals operator in an assignment statement. Remove the whitespace when assigning `$MY_RESULT`:

`MY_RESULTS="$(curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET http://localhost/test/store/widget/123)"`